# "Delete this answered question?" dialog shows up but it's not my question

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

I just got shown the "Delete this answered question?" dialog for a question that isn't mine. I *think* (it's not easy to reproduce for testing) the circumstances that led to this were:

1. Try to cast a delete vote on a question
2. Get an error about being unable to delete because of linked duplicates
3. Linked duplicates are deleted
4. Try to cast the delete vote on the original question again

All this was done without any reload of the original question's page. After a reload, there was no dialog, as expected.

Comment: I'd assume the blocking "linked duplicates" is a state that requires refresh/postback to change on the open post. Seems like a client-side validation.